# Java Time Delay

Tags: java, timer

I am having trouble with the following bit of code.

```
//Send Creation email
ListServDAO.sendCreateEmail(orgId, full, request.getSession().getServletContext());
//Force a 1 minute pause
       Timer timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                //Send add members email
                ListServDAO.sendAddMembersEmail(orgId, request.getSession().getServletContext());
                }
            }, 0, 60 * 1000);
```

The sendAddMembersEmail function does not wait 1 minute to send after the sendCreateEmail function call.  I am not sure why it is not waiting even after reading the java API. I do not wish to use the Thread.sleep method because I want the user to be able to use the application while waiting for the emails to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra zero.

What you are calling is [Delayed with a Fixed-Delay Repeat Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) and what you want is a [Single Delay Non Repeat execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29).

Answer (score 2):

are you intending to repeatedly send emails?  if not, why are you using the method which takes 2 longs (i.e. "repeatedly run this task every `<period>` milliseconds")?  use the `schedule(task, delay)` method (and use a non-zero delay).

Comment: No I just want to send them once.  Using the correct schedule method fixed the issue.  Didn't even notice I had an extra 0.

Answer (score 2):

2nd parameter is the initial delay which you are passing as 0 hence it it executing it right then and there, pass 60000 second for it to wait for a minute and then send.

Since you just want it to send only once use, call [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-)

Off-topic:

You should consider using [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of `Timer`. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Comment: Definitely recommend the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this kind of problem: running a task in the background on another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have the order of the params wrong:

```
    schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
      Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay.
```

Swap the 0 and 60*1000.